# Passing results of one query to another using mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Can you please help me  to aggregate two query in mongo DB as a single.

1. Assume I search for record with tokenNumber A1238275133. The movie -A is returned in response. However I am interested in all the movies matching with movie-A's "currentlyCertified" state
2. I.e I would get record matching with Movie-A and Movie-C

Basically I need to aggregate these two queries in to one using mongoose/ nodejs. could you please help

```
{
    "id": "123000078700723542342",
    "virtualStage": [{
        "movie": "A",
        "currentlyCertified": "Yes",
        "tokenNumber": "A1238275133",
    }]
},
{

    "id": "123000078700723542343",
    "virtualStage": [{
        "movie": "B",
        "currentlyCertified": "No",
        "tokenNumber": "A1238275138",
    }]
},
{

    "id": "123000078700723542344",
    "virtualStage": [{
        "movie": "C",
        "currentlyCertified": "Yes",
        "tokenNumber": "A1238275139",
    }]
}
```

Comment: If it is in MongoDB query, are you ok with it? In MongoDB can you please try with $or operator?

Comment: yes that should be fine.

Comment: $or might not work in my case. This is like i need to both the subqueries to get executed. Results of first subquery is a query for second subqueries

Comment: Can you put one query in the other query by wrapping the 2nd one in the first .then block if you are using promises. If you're async await, if you set the first query to a variable and use the variable for the 2nd query. Doesn't this work